# Lenses Kafka utilities are exiting with a timed out waiting message

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running kafka using the Lenses box tools. here are the steps:

**1) Install and run lenses Box: Done**

https://docs.lenses.io/dev/lenses-box/index.html#development-environment

http://localhost:3030 is running fine, I can log in and see the admin panel

**2) Run the bash shell command in the terminal: Don**e

sudo docker run --rm -it --net=host landoop/fast-data-dev bash

**3)Create a new topic with CLI : Error occurs**

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic my-topic
Exception in thread "main" kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:242)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:238)
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1825)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$ZookeeperTopicService$.apply(TopicCommand.scala:262)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:53)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

None of the kafka utilities is running, **what did I miss?**

Comment: FWIW, Docker compose / minikube of all components is more flexible than a single image

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

Run

```
sudo docker exec -it <NAME_OF_YOUR_DOCKER> bash
```

the name of the docker can be specified when running the lenses box command, just add --name=